# Tkinter start/stop button for recording audio in Python

Tags: python, audio, tkinter, pyaudio, recording

I am writing a program to record audio with the use of a Tkinter GUI. For recording audio itself, I use this code: https://gist.github.com/sloria/5693955 in nonblocking mode.

Now I want to implement something like a start/stop button, but feel like I am missing out on something. Following suppositions:

1. I can't use a `while True`statement either a `time.sleep()`function because it's going to break the Tkinter `mainloop()`
2. As a result, I will probably have to use a global `bool` to check whether my `start_recording()`function is running
3. I will have to call `stop_recording` in the same function as `start_recording`because both have to use the same object
4. I can not use `root.after()` call because I want the recording to be user-defined.

Find a code snippet of the problem below:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Button
import recorder

running = False

button_rec = Button(self, text='Aufnehmen', command=self.record)
button_rec.pack()

button_stop = Button(self, text='Stop', command=self.stop)
self.button_stop.pack()

rec = recorder.Recorder(channels=2)

def stop(self):
    self.running = False

def record(self):
    running = True
    if running:
        with self.rec.open('nonblocking.wav', 'wb') as file:
            file.start_recording()
            if self.running == False:
                file.stop_recording()

root = tk.Tk()
root.mainloop()
```

I know there has to be a loop somewhere, but I don't know where (and how).

Comment: Pick one from [`[python][tkinter] start stop`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59684860/tkinter-crashing-on-garbage-collected-variable-tkinter-tclerror-cant-set-py?noredirect=1#comment105529208_59684860)

Comment: I would uses global `file` variable and uses `file = open()`. And then I would uses `file.stop_recording()` in `stop()`

Comment: Here's an example for a GUI recorder with start/stop buttons: [rec_gui.py](https://github.com/spatialaudio/python-sounddevice/blob/master/examples/rec_gui.py). It's not using PyAudio, but it might be helpful nevertheless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `with` I would use normal

```
running = rec.open('nonblocking.wav', 'wb')

running.stop_recording()
```

so I would use it in two functions - `start` and `stop` - and I wouldn't need any loop for this.

I would need only global variable `running` to have access to recorder in both functions.

```
import tkinter as tk
import recorder

# --- functions ---

def start():
    global running

    if running is not None:
        print('already running')
    else:
        running = rec.open('nonblocking.wav', 'wb')
        running.start_recording()

def stop():
    global running

    if running is not None:
        running.stop_recording()
        running.close()
        running = None
    else:
        print('not running')

# --- main ---

rec = recorder.Recorder(channels=2)
running = None

root = tk.Tk()

button_rec = tk.Button(root, text='Start', command=start)
button_rec.pack()

button_stop = tk.Button(root, text='Stop', command=stop)
button_stop.pack()

root.mainloop()
```