# how to start and stop recording with single button

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, python-multithreading, pyaudio

I am having an issue with this code, when I try to run this code with two separate buttons it runs fine but when I try to use only a single button to start and stop the recording by changing its text(label) to start and stop recording the code does not work. The text of the button changes but it does not record anything.

```
import tkinter as tk
import threading
import pyaudio
import wave
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.font as font
from tkinter.filedialog import asksaveasfile

class App():
    chunk = 1024 
    sample_format = pyaudio.paInt16 
    channels = 2
    fs = 44100 
    def __init__(self,master):

        self.isrecording = False
        self.frames = []
        myFont = font.Font(weight="bold")
        self.button1 = tk.Button(main, text='Record',command=self.change,height=2,width=20,bg='#0052cc', fg='#ffffff')
        #self.button2 = tk.Button(main, text='stop',command=self.stoprecording,height=2,width=20,bg='#0052cc', fg='#ffffff')
        self.button1['font'] = myFont
        self.button1.place(x=30, y=30)

    def startrecording(self):

        self.isrecording = True
        self.p = pyaudio.PyAudio()  
        self.stream = self.p.open(format=self.sample_format,channels=self.channels,rate=self.fs,frames_per_buffer=self.chunk,input=True)


        print('Recording')
        t = threading.Thread(target=self.record)
        t.start()
    def stoprecording(self):

        self.isrecording = False
        print('recording complete')


        self.filename = asksaveasfile(initialdir = "/",title = "Save as",mode='wb',filetypes = (("audio file","*.wav"),("all files","*.*")),defaultextension=".wav")

        wf = wave.open(self.filename)
        wf.setnchannels(self.channels)
        wf.setsampwidth(self.p.get_sample_size(self.sample_format))
        wf.setframerate(self.fs)
        wf.writeframes(b''.join(self.frames))
        wf.close()
        main.destroy()
    def change(self):
        if self.button1['text'] == 'Record':
            self.startrecording()
            self.isrecording = True
            self.button1.config(text="Stop")
        else:
            self.stoprecording()
            self.isrecording = False
            self.button1.config(text="Record")
    def record(self):

        while self.isrecording:
            data = self.stream.read(self.chunk)
            self.frames.append(data)



main = tk.Tk()
main.title('recorder')
main.geometry('520x120')
app = App(main)
main.mainloop()
```

error image
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tkinter start/stop button for recording audio in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59686267/tkinter-start-stop-button-for-recording-audio-in-python)

Comment: @shaikmoeed no this question is totally different i am using pyaudio check above its different

Comment: Your code did not call `startrecording()` and `stoprecording()` functions inside `change()` function.

Comment: It doesn't actually matter to achieve your expected results, you can follow the same logic mentioned in the above link.

Comment: @acw1668 (code updated) now its recording but its 0 bytes file. check the errors i mention above.

Comment: It is because you have set `self.isrecording = 0` in `startrecording()`.

Comment: @acw1668 updated now its recording but the same error is showing again why?

Comment: Are you running your script inside an IDE?  Since you have not called `main.mainloop()` at the end of your code, the GUI should not be shown.

Comment: @acw1668 the Gui is showing and its recording also but still showing the errors. i am using python default Idle

Comment: The reason is that your code has destroyed the main window in `stoprecording()`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208385/discussion-between-cb9867-and-acw1668).